# Ploneboard error after upgrading Plone 4.0.5 to 4.1.3

Tags: plone

When starting a conversation, entering Title and Body text and press the save button (blue disk) I get this error in the log:

```
ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1326636216.360.72448689069 http://.../netop/dokumenter/forum/forum/festudvalget/tinymce-save
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.TinyMCE.browser.browser, line 33, in save
  Module Products.TinyMCE.adapters.Save, line 18, in save
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

When pressing "Post comment":
INFO PloneboardNotification FIRING event for obj /netop/dokumenter/forum/forum/festudvalget/29222752/136755643

Then when trying to see the conversation at the link:

```
http://.../netop/dokumenter/forum/forum/festudvalget/29222752
```

, and Plone says that something with:

```
"Sorry, the page does not exist. Try to contact the Administrator."
```

PS I found out that my Ploneboard 3.1 version was not up todate. I changed to 4.1.3 in "find-links" in base.cfg and made a "bin/buildout -n" which updated Ploneboard to 3.2.

I still have the error though and in the add-on it still says:

```
"Install the intranet workflow definitions for Ploneboard."
```

There is also a red exclamation mark saying something with:

```
"This add-on is upgraded with an old profile version uknown. New profile version is 1.0. There is no upgrade defined for this add-on."
```

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed also needed "Workflow Policy Support (CMFPlacefulWorkflow) 1.5.6". I think there was a bug where this add-on was not automatically added with some version of ploneboard. I upgraded from ploneboard 2.0 (and Plone 3.1) on the weekend and I needed to remove ploneboard, SimpleAttachment, and kupu and add ploneboard back to get things working correctly.

Don't forget to make a back before trying out big changes like this. I had some issues in my initial tests with removing and then adding ploneboard.

Comment: Thanks it worked. There is still an error in the "add-on" for Ploneboard 3.2 though - it says: Install the intranet workflow definitions for Ploneboard. Also: This add-on is upgraded with an old profile version uknown. New profile version is 1.0. There is no upgrade defined for this add-on. Any ideas to solve that? Thanks. Nikolaj G.

Comment: I don't know about the first question, but I still have the New profile version is 1.0 issue as well. I think this is related to the content_migration mechanism and the Ploneboard does not actually do anything with it at this point and we won't be able to get rid of it without Ploneboard doing something about it.